# Função Keydown pulando um input no TAB

Tags: jquery, formulário, input

Boa tarde, tenho uma função que quando aperto o enter ele cria uma nova série de inputs na primeira linha empurrando as preenchidas para baixo, fiz com que ao apertar o tab na ultima também ocorra a mesma função, porém, quando aperto o enter, independente do input que estiver, ele cria outra cadeia de input colocando o foco no primeiro input, exatamente como programei, perfeito, já no tab, que é para funcionar só no último input que no caso já está assim, o erro é, com o enter, ele foca no primeiro input, como o tab ele foca no segundo input, ignorando o primeiro, como isso ocorre se é o mesmo código para os dois?

```
    $(document).on('keydown', 'input', function(enter) {
        if (enter.which == 13) {
            new_input(); } });

    $(document).on('keydown', 'input.val', function(tab) {
        if (tab.which == 9) {
            new_input(); } });
```

A função que cria nova cadeia de inputs e foca no primeiro é esta

```
        function new_input() {
        $('<x>'
            + '<input class="cod" id="focus' + rscn +'" placeholder="Código" />'
            + '<input class="desc" placeholder="Descrição" />'
            + '<div class="div"></div>'
            + '<input class="quant" placeholder="Quantidade" />'
            + '<input class="val" placeholder="Valor" />'
            + '<span id="remove_item" class="remove cursor_pointer display_none">+</span>'
        + '</x>').prependTo(scntDiv);
        $('#focus' + rscn).focus();
        rscn++;
        mais('itens_total');
        return false; }
```

o erro está apenas no tab, ele pula o primeiro input

Comment: Utilize a área de respostas para postar a sua solução, não utilize o próprio enunciado. Se possível, remova a resposta da pergunte e converta-a para uma resposta,d e fato.

Comment: não entendo, quando vou fazer isso, o próprio stack fala para não o fazer, pede para eu editar a pergunta, acreditar em quem afinal

Comment: @flourigh o proprio stack ou alguem que participa do stack? O que a pessoa deve ter falado é sobre adicionar detalhes da duvida no campo de resposta, você quem deve ter entendido errado =)

Comment: Quando for responder a própria dúvida, o site diz: "*Se quer fornecer mais detalhes sobre seu problema, edite sua pergunta.*". No caso, uma resposta não é detalhe da pergunta, então pode postá-se sem medo. Há isso porque muitos membros acham que é um fórum e tentam continuar a discussão postando respostas, ao invés de inserir os novos detalhes direto na pergunta.

Comment: valew, fiz o que recomendou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit

Resolvi depois de muitos, mas muitos testes frustrados, vou colocar o código para quem estiver passando por o mesmo caso, tive que inserir um monte de funções dentro do tab para que funcionasse direito

```
        $(document).on('keydown', 'input.last', function(tab) {
            if(tab.which == 9) {
/* tira o foco do ultimo input */
                $(this).blur();
/* previne focar no proximo */
                event.preventDefault();
/* procura o primeiro input */
                $('input.first').first().focus();
/* cria nova linha de inputs */
                new_input(); } });
```

se alguém souber uma forma menor de fazer isso, aceito sugestões.